# Wordpress custom archives format

Tags: wordpress

Trying to figure out how to build an archives page that displays in the format that I want. I want to show all posts, ordered by date. Should look like:

```
February 2010
   6           Post-Title
   3           Post-Title

January 2010
   29          Post-Title
   etc...
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the specifics of the loop that needs to be created. I'm on Wordpress 3.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've once solve this for WP 2.9.something like this:

*And yes! I know: the indentation of the mark-up looks messed up, but it (sorta) makes sense, if you look carefully ;)*

This is not tested anymore with WP 3.0.x, but it did pretty much exactly what you wanted. Please see if it works for you and feel free to ask if something is broken or doesn't make sense.

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <?php $year = 0; ?>
    <?php $month = 0; ?>
        <ul>

    <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?> 
        <?php $post_year = substr($post->post_date, 0, 4);  ?>
        <?php $post_month = substr($post->post_date, 5, 2);  ?>
        <?php if(($year != $post_year || $month != $post_month) && $year != 0): ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($year != $post_year || $month != $post_month): ?>
            <li>
                <strong><?php the_time('F Y') ?></strong>
                <ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
                    <li>
                        <span><?= mysql2date('j', $post->post_date) ?></span>
                        <?php the_title() ?>
                    </li>
        <?php $year = $post_year; ?>
        <?php $month = $post_month; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Works on my 3.0.4 install. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Please consider marking this answer as correct it works for you. Cheers.